# Spring AOP @After advice causing exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm getting getting exception on trying to execute Spring AOP @After advice:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAO' defined in file [C:\Users\sonue\Documents\learn\springaop\target\classes\com\sonu\springaop\dao\EmployeeDAO.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: EmployeeDAO [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: EmployeeDAO [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Below is how my code looks:

```
@After("execution(* EmployeeDAO.getEmployeeById(..))")         //point-cut expression
public void logAfterV1(JoinPoint joinPoint)
{
    System.out.println("EmployeeCRUDAspect.logAfterV1() : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@After("execution(* com.sonu.springaop.dao.EmployeeDAO.getEmployeeById(..))")         //point-cut expression
public void logAfterV1(JoinPoint joinPoint)
{
    System.out.println("EmployeeCRUDAspect.logAfterV1() : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

use fully qualified name of class with the package name.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with the following expression.Didn't have to use fully qualified classname. Try the following

```
@After("execution(* *..EmployeeDAO.getEmployeeID(..))")
```

Answer (score 0):

provide absolute name for `EmployeeDAO` fox example `com.company.project.x.y.z. EmployeeDAO`